# Vertical space and its size

Tags: spacing

I don't know if somebody has already asked, but:
how should I do a vertical space of a size of a half/quarter of page?

Comment: Is this Ok?    \setlength{\parskip}{0.25\paperheight}

Comment: @user32680 It depends on what you want to do, but I'd say that generally using `\parskip` for this is not recommended. Can you tell something more about your needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `\vspace` with the appropriate fraction of `\textheight` or `\paperheight`...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

As egreg says in the comments, the space will be removed if it occurs at the top of a page. If you want the space in that case, just use `\vspace*` in place of `\vspace`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And the solution posted by me is also OK?